# How do I list everyone who has ever committed to a file in Git?

Tags: git, dvcs, command-line-interface, blame

I want to get a complete list of everyone who has ever committed to a file, is there a command (blame with some arguments, maybe) do that nicely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about all **authors** of commits touching given file, then

```
git shortlog --numbered --summary HEAD --follow <filename>
```

would be a solution.

Please note however thet the `--follow` option doesn't always work correctly acros renames in more complicated (less linear) history.

Answer (score 2):

```
git shortlog -se filename
```

Comment: If the file has been renamed or copied, then this command may not catch some commits.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gitk filename` or `git whatchanged -p filename`.